# Light SES2 drive failure light from Linux?

Tags: linux, diskmanagement

With a SES2 capable backplane and SAS card, is it possible to light the drive failure light on a specific bay from Linux?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with [Enclosure LED Utilities](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ledmon/) with the following command:

`ledctl failure=/dev/diskdevice`

Answer (score -1):

This is a controller feature -- you need to use tools and software specific to the controller to be able to do that.

Without the make and model it's hard to tell anything more.

Comment: [SES-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SES-2_Enclosure_Management) specifies a standard interface to the enclosure management. Thus if the controller complies with the specification (as stated in the question), there is no need to use controller specific software.